# XBox Joystick - detecting signal loss

Tags: joystick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ran into a weird behavior (i.e. crashing my robot uncontrollable into a wall) because while operating the robot, the battery shutdown. Due to the autorepeat function inside the [joy_node](http://docs.ros.org/api/joy/html/#parameters), the last command was infinitely repeated until crash.

The question here is, if there is any option for the xbox controller to find out if signal is lost or still available.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220442/xbox-joystick---detecting-signal-loss/) by [Karsten](https://answers.ros.org/users/8211/karsten/) on ROS Answers with karma: 643 on 2015-11-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had a similar problem with the xbox controller publishing garbage messages on startup and messing things up. I switched to the xboxdrv driver and have no more problems. It looks like it also publishes a no-buttons-pushed joy message when I take the battery out.

[Here's how to set it up.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/165210/how-do-i-get-an-xbox-360-controller-working)

<s>NOTE: It switches the pad buttons to be axes, so you'll have to change up your nodes using the joy message.</s> EDIT: I hadn't read far enough in the man page, but it's highly configurable.

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2015-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0